Configuring a USB-C/PD Controller IC for a Type-A Output
I'm working on a new USB charging product to be installed on airplanes. I understand the power requirements well enough: it has to take 12V-32V input and be able to provide up to 45W of power per output with >95% efficiency. I'm looking into a GaN FET buck converter for that part.
What I really need help with is understanding which USB controller IC to use. We want to be able to have a USB-C only option, and an option with USB-C and USB-A. Maybe a dual USB-C output option as well.
While researching this, I found the reference design PMP40543, which uses the same nominally USB-C controller chip for both the USB-C and the USB-A output. I don't want to use this specific chip, however, because it has a built-in buck converter. Given the power and efficiency requirements, I need to find an IC to communicate with an external buck converter.
The idea of using a USB-C controller for the USB-A output appeals to me because it would allow me to use a dual-port USB-C controller for both the USB-C and USB-A outputs simultaneously. Or, I could use two of the same USB-C controllers for both the USB-C and USB-A outputs.
What are the requirements and restrictions when configuring a USB-C controller IC for a USB-A output? I need to understand what we can and can't do to make an informed decision for the direction of this project.
If anyone can provide insight into this aspect of USB charger design, I would greatly appreciate it. Thank you.


What voltages and protocols you need to support on Type-A port? It might not make any sense to use a Type-A port with a Type-C PD controller, if it does not allow communicating charging protocols available on Type-A.

As many as we can get away with, basically. I found a USB-A port wall charger that supports 5V 3A, 9V 2A, and 12V 1.5A. We want to match that for the USB-A port, if nothing else. I think that has something to do with Qualcomm's Quick Charge standard, but I have found that particularly difficult to research.

Exactly, the reason why it is difficult to research is that the standards are not public. So you can't implement it yourself unless you buy a membership. But you can always buy the chips that implement the charging protocols as the chip manufacturers are members and royalties are included when you buy these chips, which basically you don't know what they do except implement the secret handshakes. They are often inregrated with the buck converter for all-in-one solution. Any mistake with communicating with external regulator and it may fry you 5V only device.

Yes, that tracks. But how do I identify the chips that will do what I need them to do? I want to be able to offer a broad range of voltage and power options on the USB-A connector, but I definitely don't want to damage a customer device.

Chip vendors state what they support, on web pages or data sheets. It might be impossible to find a chip that communicates all the protocols you can ever think of, each vendor has their own. And the problem is also that can you even find a Type-A connector that is officially rated for 3A or whatever current you need? I don't think you can get your product USB certified unless you use connectors and protocols like USB BC as a base and each protocol vendor might also require you to certify your product passes the protocol tests as required. Otherwise you can't advertize support for that protocol

They probably do say what they support on data sheets. The problem is, I can't tell from the data sheet whether or not these ICs will do what I need them to. I don't know what I'm looking for. And yes, there are USB-A connectors that can handle this kind of current. I have a USB-A wall adapter on my desk that can output 5V 3A, 9V 2A, and 12V 1.5A. I need something like that, but it's hard to research because everyone wants to do USB-C these days.
